# What kinds of attacks can VLAN's mitigate?

Tags: network, exploit

Assuming these very basic kinds of attacks:

- Header based
- Protocol based
- Authentication based
- Traffic based

What would using a VLAN mitigate?

Several people seem to be overthinking the question. The attacks mentioned above are the 4 attack types in the network security attack taxonomy. I realize they are generic, but I was hoping for a moderately generic answer.

Comment: Is this a homework question? Where did the list of "basic attacks" come from?

Comment: They are just the 4 basic attacks in the network security taxonomy.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for - the question itself appears to be a homework question requiring a certain amount of knowledge already. Please read [about] and [ask] to see what we need in a question.

Comment: @RoryAlsop, as mentioned previously, these kinds of attacks are the 4 components of the network security attack types. The answer to the question has been marked if you'd like to see exactly how I was hoping the question would be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traffic based. An example of an traffic based attack would be sniffing. By implementing VLANs, you seggragate traffic into different VLANs so that traffic that belongs to one VLAN is only visible in that VLAN. If there were no VLANs, an ARP spoofing attack could affect the whole switched network. In case there are VLANs, it would affect only the VLAN on which it is happening.

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was thinking, but your examples really help further my thoughts. Thank you much.